# Conda tab is not showing in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook, conda

While running Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu 14.4 from a Conda environment, the Conda tab is supposed to be present but it's missing. Also, all options for Conda environment specific notebooks are missing when clicking new.

Comment: Can you try installing the `conda_nb` package? I think that package provides all of that functionality. https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/jupyter-notebook-extensions

Comment: I did try that previously and got a strange error message. The good news is that I'll be "dumping" and will probably use a new one soon.